# How can I run IOS Simulator without Xcode 14?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, simulator

I was wondering if there is some trick to bypass the latest Xcode to run IOS Simulator for Flutter Apps, I currently have Xcode 12 and my mac is old so can't get Xcode 14, is there a way that can be bypassed? Please let me know!

The simulator works only in xcode when you run it through the Runner file though, but I need hot refresh and realtime device!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Downgrade Flutter?

Comment: IOS simulator is not something that can be launched independently without XCode. Can't you update the version of Mac OS so you can install a later Xcode?

Comment: No I can't I have a 2015 mac